# Dialog Widget. How do I programmatically call the ok method when I hit return key

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI dialog widget. I have a function associated with the "ok" key within the buttons object:

```
var myself = this;

    this.dialogForm.dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "ok": ok,
                    cancel: function() {
                        myself.dialogForm.dialog( "close" );
                    }
                },
                close: function() {
                    myself.form[ 0 ].reset();
                    myself.dialogForm.remove();
                    myself.dialogForm = undefined;
                    if (trackMenu) trackMenu.hide();
                }
            });
```

How do I programmatically call the `ok` function when I press the return key. I want to get rid of the need for the user to mouse over and click the ok button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event listener when the jQuery UI modal is open.

**Very** basic example:

```
function modalEnterKeyPress (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) 
        return ok()    
}

// When you open the modal
$(document.body).one('keyup', modalEnterKeyPress);

// When you close the modal
$(document.body).off('keyup', modalEnterKeyPress);
```

Comment: Nifty. Thanks Martin.

Comment: Glad I could help :) FYI `event.keyCode` is supposedly deprecated, `event.key` should be used. But, for some reason, I couldn't get it to work so I stuck with `keyCode`